# C# Entity Framework including neighbor tables with include() terrible performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, include

I have a query which looks like following:

```
users = ctx.SearchedUsers.AsNoTracking()
           .IncludeEFU(ctx,c=>c.SearchedUserItems)
           .IncludeEFU(ctx,c=>c.UserTransactions)
           .Where(y => y.InQueue == false && 
                       y.LastTimeSearchedAt.Value > inPast10Dayss)
           .OrderBy(y => y.LastUpdatedAt)
           .Take(100).ToList();
```

The `IncludeEFU()` method is called via EFUtilities library which I got from here:

```
https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities
```

And another version of this query (using regular include) looks like this:

```
users = ctx.SearchedUsers.AsNoTracking()
           .Include("SearchedUserItems")
           .Include("UserTransactions")
           .Where(y => y.InQueue == false && 
                       y.LastTimeSearchedAt.Value > inPast10Dayss)
           .OrderBy(y => y.LastUpdatedAt)
           .Take(100).ToList();
```

Now both of these queries give terrible performance results, where taking 100 records from `SearchedUsers` table with approximately anywhere between 2000 to 5000 records in the two neighboring tables `SearchedUserItems` and `UserTransactions` take anywhere between 2 to 5 minutes....

What I have done earlier is pulling the records for each record from `SearchedUser` table and then pulled the neighbor records via FK (which is indexed in both tables for faster performance).

Now my question here is... Is there any faster way to include these records with one query so I don't have to pull them one by one in an efficient manner?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Anyone guys? =)

Comment: Calling `.ToList();` necessary? Because that will definitely impact the performance

Comment: @Izzy I can try without ... let's see how much will it affect performance..

Comment: If you don't need to execute the query straight away then there's no need to call `.ToList()`

Comment: Just one of those includes could cause 200,000 - 500,000 rows to be returned.  Have you looked at the SQL?

Comment: @Izzy I do need to execute it right away :/

Comment: @MarkPeters Yes I'm aware... If there was only some way to filter them by the FK, since that one is indexed =/

Comment: Do you need full objects?  I'd be inclined to do this as two queries (searcheduseritems and usertransactions), both with the same filter on SearchedUsers, selecting only the fields that I needed

Comment: and use an OrderBy() clause if you are going to use Take()

Comment: @MarkPeters these are IEnumerable<Type> types inside SearchedUsers, whole lists...

Comment: @MarkPeters orderby which property ? ^^

Comment: @MarkPeters p.s. I already user order by... It's not visible right away, but if you scrool to the right you'll see its' there... Order by is by the indexed column :D

Comment: How long it takes if you execute the query w/o Includes? With just first Include? With just second Include?

Comment: What are you doing with your child tables?  You're really getting a lot of data back

Comment: @MarkPeters yes there's a lot of data returned with the child tables... I'm using the child tables data to calculate the parent data stats, and update the child tables...

Comment: Can you try SQL Profiler, check what queries EF creates for this and how long they take to run?

Comment: Is this EF or EF Core? What SQL is being generated? (Consider LINQPad.) Did you mean 2000-5000 records per `SearchedUsers` record or 2000-5000 records for 100 `SearchedUsers` records? Can you move the `Include`s after the `Take`?

Comment: I would definitely check the raw SQL generated by that LINQ statement. It could also be worth looking at what happens when you remove those `where` clauses. If you see a performance boost, re-introduce them one-by-one. what happens? could indexes on/around these columns and/or the 'include' tables help?

Comment: Alternative - could you retrieve `SearchedUserItems` and `UserTransactions` in separate queries then join them in to your main LINQ statement rather than using the `Include` statement? If the relationship between `SearchedUsers` and those 2 tables isn't quite right it could be the root of the evil you are seeing!